# Iframe breaks when used with gravity forms

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe, gravity-forms-plugin

I am building a wordpress site and trying to integrate iframe as well as using gravity form.

If in case in disabling the gravity form plugin, the iframe is rendered as desired.
But in case, if the form plugin is enabled , the iframe is not rendered properly.

You can look at the following link to know how iframe is rendered when plugin is activated:

[image]

I don't want to use any javascript. want to purely render through Html/css